Using DuckDB C API to append Array type
I have an existing DuckDB database with a table that has the schema:
name: VARCHAR location: VARCHAR lucky_numbers: UINTEGER[5]
and I want to add a row using DuckDB's C API.
// .. already connected to database
duckdb_appender appender;
duckdb_appender_create(db_connection, NULL, db_table, &appender);
duckdb_append_varchar(appender, "John Doe");
duckdb_append_varchar(appender, "Switzerland");
// TODO: append an Array of of 5 integers

duckdb_appender_end_row(appender);
duckdb_appender_destroy(&appender);


I've read here that you can use duckdb_append_data_chunk to append array types, but I'm not sure how to use that function to do so. How do I use that method to append an array?

I've never used this API before, but based on the documentation I'm going to guess that you use duckdb_create_data_chunk to create a data chunk containing one column of the appropriate array type (which probably needs to be created using duckdb_create_array_type), and then use duckdb_append_data_chunk to append the data chunk to your appender.
